# how to use a signed user certificate with mobaxterm

Tags: windows, ssh

I am a unix/linux guy.  I have setup a server installation for our racked machines and our cloud VMs to configure sshd to trust signed user certificates, those signed by the trusted CA.

Everything is working fine using ssh-add and ssh-agent on linux and on macosx.

One guy has a windows client, using mobaxterm.  From the documentation, it has some support for ssh-agent and pageant.

I can get a public key from him, and sign it just fine.  But, where does the resulting certificate go?

Answer (score 0):

MobaXterm has a virtual mapping, usually in `%Documents%\MobaXterm\home`. Alternatively, you can go to `Settings>Configuration>General` and see where the persistent home directory is set. You can create a folder `.ssh` here, then put your private key, public key, and signed certificate in this folder.

If you do not want to store your keys here, you can create a file at `/home/.ssh/config`, and specify an Identity, including a mapping to the path of all three of those files. The drives of the computer will be mounted under `/drives/%drive_letter%` so you will need to convert your Windows path.

`C:\Documents and Settings` becomes `/drives/c/Documents\ and\ Settings`